# Mapreduce Inputformat performance in using InputStreamReader.read()

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to develop a custom input format for mapreduce. I was using inputStreamReader.read(). This will read data as character by character. Does this cause performance degradation. Or can I read the data into a configurable sized buffer and then read characters from the buffer? . Which approach will be good in terms of performance.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can wrap your inputStream with BufferedReader to achieve the reading of chars from a buffered input. Look for an example here.  : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html. BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Comment: Does using BufferedReader  brings performance improvement ?

Comment: Yes, it does improve the performance as it buffers the data into a memory and then read from there